# Python Pandas: Transforming dataframe according to a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with offer data that I want to transform into portion data. The column *quantity* tells how many portions each offer has. If an offer has three portions out of which two were sold, that row should appear three times in the new dataframe, so that the *sold* column has value 1 on two rows and value 0 on one row.

The actual dataframe contains more columns that should stay intact in the transformed dataframe. *Date* column works as an example.

My input:

```
    Offer name     Quantity   Sold   Date
  0 A              3          2      2022-05 
  1 B              2          1      2022-01 
  2 C              1          1      2022-04 
  3 D              1          1      2022-04 
  4 E              1          1      2022-05
```

The desired output:

```
    Offer name     Quantity   Sold   Date
  0 A              1          1      2022-05 
  1 A              1          1      2022-05 
  2 A              1          0      2022-05 
  3 B              1          1      2022-01 
  4 B              1          0      2022-01
  and so on...
```

Thank you!!

Comment: What if `Sold` is greater than `Quantity`?

Comment: It's impossible in this dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

```
s = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['Quantity']))
s['Quantity'] = 1
s['Sold'] = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount().lt(s['Sold']).astype(int)
```

#### Explained

Repeat the index of dataframe exactly `Quantity` times

```
>>> s = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['Quantity']))
>>> s

  Offer name  Quantity  Sold     Date
0          A         3     2  2022-05
0          A         3     2  2022-05
0          A         3     2  2022-05
1          B         2     1  2022-01
1          B         2     1  2022-01
2          C         1     1  2022-04
3          D         1     1  2022-04
4          E         1     1  2022-05
```

Group the above dataframe on index and use `cumcount` to create a sequential counter,

```
>>> s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
0    0
0    1
0    2
1    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Flag the rows where the sequential counter is less than `Sold` quantity then change the dtype to `int` and assign the result to `Sold` column

```
>>> s['Sold'] = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount().lt(s['Sold']).astype(int)
>>> s

  Offer name  Quantity  Sold     Date
0          A         1     1  2022-05
0          A         1     1  2022-05
0          A         1     0  2022-05
1          B         1     1  2022-01
1          B         1     0  2022-01
2          C         1     1  2022-04
3          D         1     1  2022-04
4          E         1     1  2022-05
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try apply on rows

```py
def repeat(row):
    offer = [row['Offer name']] * row['Quantity']
    sold = [1] * row['Sold'] + [0] * (row['Quantity']-row['Sold'])
    return offer, sold, 1

df[['Offer name', 'Sold', 'Quantity']] = df.apply(repeat, axis=1, result_type='expand')
df = df.explode(['Offer name', 'Sold'])
```

```
print(df)

  Offer name  Quantity Sold     Date
0          A         1    1  2022-05
0          A         1    1  2022-05
0          A         1    0  2022-05
1          B         1    1  2022-01
1          B         1    0  2022-01
2          C         1    1  2022-04
3          D         1    1  2022-04
4          E         1    1  2022-05
```

Comment: Thanks! This was also a clear way to solve the problem.